# Java error 'No such file or directory error' on java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am doing a java course online and I have copied the code from the video, but when I go into Eclipse's workspace and bin folder, there is no `FileInput.txt` folder on my MacBook.

Any help would be appreciated!

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Bytestreams {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileInputStream input = null;

        input = new FileInputStream("FileInput.txt");

        int number;

        while((number = input.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

That is my code and the error I get is:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: FileInput.txt (No such file or directory)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
> at Bytestreams.main(Bytestreams.java:11)
> ```

Comment: This code is expecting that that file already exists with text in it.

Comment: either use the full path:    '`input = new FileInputStream("C:/the/actual/path/to/FileInput.txt"); `'  or put the txt file into the same directory as your .java file (not the .jar file)

Answer (score 2):

Your file structure should be like this:

```
|-- Bytestreams.java
|-- FileInput.txt
```